# Proteger banco de dados SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tenho 2 bancos de dados SQL Server no meu SQL Server Management Studio.

Gostaria de colocar senha em um dos dois, impossibilitando acesso ao mesmo, é possível?

Comment: O SQL Server Management Studio é apenas uma ferramenta para acessar o seu banco de dados. Você tem 2 bancos de dados no SQL Server e não no SSMS. Sobre a questão: basicamente, você não pode colocar uma senha no banco em si, precisa criar um usuário, definir uma senha pra ele e adicionar ele nas permissões do banco de dados específico.

Answer (score 5):

No banco de dados em si não é possível. O que você pode fazer é alterar quais usuários têm acesso ao banco, lembre que o usuário *master* (aquele definido na instalação do banco, geralmente nomeado como *sa*) sempre vai ter acesso a todos os bancos.

Para alterar os usuários que têm acesso à *database*, é só expandir *Security* e depois *Users* (*Logins*).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: e como faço para não ter acesso pela autenticação do windows?

Comment: @RonaldoSantos Tem que desativar a autenticação do Windows. Seria uma boa abrir outra pergunta sobre isso, não acha?

Answer (score 3):

Você deve abrir o `Object Explorer do Sql`, expandir o Servidor, `Security -> Logins`, lá você pode adicionar um usuário, e em `User` `Mapping` checar as bases de dados que deseja permitir.

Para permitir `Sql Authentication`, click com botão direito no servidor, em `Security` checar `Sql Server and Windows Authentication Mode`.